# Server returned nothing (no headers, no data) when uploading/downloading larger files

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, nginx-ingress

when uploading or downloading larger files (bigger than 30 MB), I am occasionally getting this exception:

```
"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the 
 request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: Server returned nothing (no 
 headers, no data)   at 
 System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error) at   
 System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAgent.FinishRequest(StrongToWeakReference`1 easyWrapper, CURLcode messageResult)
```

It is  a .NET Core 2.0 web app running in Linux/nginx environment. So, sometimes the uploads/downloads of the very same files  are performed without problems, sometimes I am getting the 'no headers, no data' exception and sometimes I can get also 502 Bad gateway or 504 gateway timeout error exception.

It is multilayer environment where the request is forwarded firstly to microservice in orchestration layer and then microservice in service layer.

Any idea/advice?

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#troubleshooting and https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267 and most importantly this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#uploading-large-files-with-streaming ?

Comment: @Tseng, the only thing I haven't tried is uploading using streaming. Since the app  I am talking about is not in production, it is unbelievable that .NET Core itself is not able to buffer a file of 37 MB since I am the single user. Running in Visual studio, in docker environment - upload operation succeeds every single time. I would say that the problem is specific for Linux/nginx/.NET Core combination.. Oh, and very important - it is running in multilayer service architecture where the request is post further to orchestration layer and then service layer..

Comment: You have provided very little information in your question. whats your nginx settings? Most webservers have a limit on http body size. The linked ones tell you the limits for ASP.NET Core and IIS. You should check nginx limits and default values

Comment: I do not have a direct access to nginx, but The DevOps already edited it since the limit was very low (4MB I think).. I can upload now also the bigger files, but occasionally I get exceptions as I described in initial post. All the errors indicate some interruption of communication between layers.